# non-negative $\{f_n\}$ such that $\int f_{n}d\mu=1$ but not $f_{n}/n \to 0$ a.e.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(\mathbb{X},\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space. Let $f_n \in L^{1}(\mu)$ be non-negative functions satisfying
$$\int_{\mathbb{X}} f_{n}d\mu=1$$

(a) Show that it is not necessarily true that $f_{n}/n \to 0$ a.e.

(b) Show that $f_{n}/n^{2} \to 0$ a.e.

---

I solved (b) using the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$ .

So naturally in order to solve (a) I tried to find some example that leads to the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}=\infty$ . But any example I've tried failed (for instance sequences of triangles with the area of 1).

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a hint. You won't get that $f_n/n$ converges to a nonzero number. But you can make sure that it doesn't converge.

Comment: Rectangles of area $1$ should work.  Make the height of the $n$'th be $n$, so the width is $1/n$. You can arrange it so infinitely many rectangles are above every $x \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

How about this example:

Let $\mathbb{X}=[0,\infty)$ and $m$ Lebesgue measure.

Let $a_n=1/n$ and $n_1=1$.

Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}=\infty$ we can find a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ such that $S_k<S_{k+1}$ for every $k$ and $S_k \to \infty$, where $S_1=a_{n_1}=1$ and $S_{k}=\sum_{n=n_{k-1}+1}^{n_k} a_{n}$ for every $k>1$.

Then we construct a sequence of functions $\{g_n\}$ as follows:
$$\chi_{[0,a_{n_1}]}, \chi_{[0,a_{n_1+1}]},\chi_{[a_{n_1+1},a_{n_1+1}+a_{n_1+2}]},..., 
\chi_{[\sum_{j=n_1+1}^{n_2-1}a_j,\sum_{j=n_1+1}^{n_2}a_j]},
\chi_{[0,a_{n_2+1}]},\chi_{[a_{n_2+1},a_{n_2+1}+a_{n_2+2}]}, ...
$$

So $\int_{\mathbb{X}} g_{n}dm=1/n$ for every $n$, but since $S_k<S_{k+1}$ and $S_k \to \infty$ we get that  $g_n(x)$ does not converge for any $x \in \mathbb{X}$, since there are infinitely many $n$ for which $g_n(x)=1$ and infinitely many for which $g_n(x)=0$.

So $f_n=n \cdot g_n$ should work.

Is this a good solution? Thanks!